# If there is a bijection between $A$ and $\operatorname{Fin}(A)$, is there a bijection between $A$ and $A\times A$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

If there is a bijection between $A$ and $\operatorname{Fin}(A)$ then there is a bijection between $A\times A$ and $A$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: i prove there is injective between N to Fin(N) and there also injective between Fin(N) to N and by Schroder- Bernstein theorem there is a bijection between N and Fin(N), but the second one i cannot do anything so i said i might be wrong or there is any way in 1 that can help me with 2

Comment: (1) Have been asked ***many*** times before. And it seems that you got it under wraps. So you might as well remove it from the question. I've answered (2), but you should perhaps elaborate on your question, what you know and don't know. And while you're at it, perhaps a better title is in order.

Comment: thanks Asaf, you help me to find the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for (2) is indeed positive.

Recall that we can encode an ordered pair $(a,b)$ as the set $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. Therefore $A\times A$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Fin}(\operatorname{Fin}(A))$.

If $A$ and $\operatorname{Fin}(A)$ have the same cardinality, show that we actually get that $A$ and $\operatorname{Fin}(\operatorname{Fin}(A))$ also have a bijection between them, and conclude from the Cantor-Bernstein theorem the wanted result.

(Note that assuming the axiom of choice this is easier, since for a finite set, $A$, $\mathcal P(A)=\operatorname{Fin}(A)$ and therefore there is no bijection between them, and for every infinite set, $A\times A$ and $A$ have a bijection between them. But the crux of the question, I suppose, is without the axiom of choice.)